# How can I group together iPad, iPhone, and iPod into "iOS" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, user-agent

In my Operating System data, iPhone, iPad, and iPod are shown as separate operating systems. Is there a way to combine all three of these into one single "iOS" operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this within GA.  You will have to export to something like excel and group them yourself.  Another alternative is to write your own OS detection code and output them as a grouped value to a GA custom variable and then look at the custom variable report instead.